# How to completely disable Airplay in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, airplay

I'd like to cut out AirPlay entirely.

Looking for an answer, I read
[Disable AirPlay on a Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53628/disable-airplay-on-a-mac)

But it didn't really offer a direct solution.

Here is my problem:

I have the household media room connected to an Airplay capable receiver.  Our media server is a secondary Mac that runs 24/7 for the express purpose of serving media throughout the house.  This is a headless machine that does not ever output any audio of its own, and in fact could have all audio drivers disabled and it would be perfectly fine with me.

What happens is, this machine appears to spontaneously decide that it wants to connect to the Airplay receiver, which causes my Media room to suddenly switch input sources and is seriously irritating and confusing to other members of the household.

If I could simply disable Airplay completely on this machine, then all would be well.  But I don't want to impact any other internet connectivity as I have multiple apps that need to communicate at all times in both directions to the outside internet.

Is there in fact a direct way to simply disable Airplay entirely in Mac OS X?

Comment: At first glance this doesn't seem to be different from the question you are referring to. Can you elaborate a bit on why the solutions offered there will not work for you?

Comment: And on second thought: Wouldn't it be better to solve the issue of auto-switching input sources?

Comment: I specifically cannot block all incoming connections because I have multiple applications that require incoming and outgoing connections.  Setting up some complex set of rules to try and allow some things through the firewall and block others, is just not at all desirable.  I need ALL standard network functionality to work, I just need to disable Airplay.  I have not found a way to do that.  I would love to solve the auto-switching, but it switches when it gets a request to do so, which is coming from the Mac so that's what I need to solve.

Comment: Feel free to add a new question to help solve the switching thing. Adding log files of the moment it happens would probably be needed then as well.

Comment: I would gladly include a log file but I have no idea what to include or where it would be.  Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Quick suggestion, plug a cheap pair of headphones into the Mac. I suspect that in the absence of other outputs, the Mac is using Airplay.  When I get home, I'll try to get screenshots of the Sound control panel to show how to change the settings, but the headphones should take precedence and be a quick fix.

Comment: Great thought, but actually there is already a physical device connected to the audio output.  I never use it but it's there.  So there is no lacking an output device.  The only option available for audio output is airplay (specifically, the Sony receiver in the other room).

Comment: Ok.  If you have a chance to check right now, go into System Preferences, Sound, click the Output tab.  See if it's defaulting to Airplay.  If so, change it to the external device.  That should change the global output.

Comment: Can't - there is no external device.  The ONLY option I have for an audio output, is my airplay receiver.  Nothing else.

Comment: I just came across this thread having the same problem. I am curious to know if you fixed the problem or not after all this time? None of the answers here managed to fix it for me... i ended up dealing with apple tech support. His answer was to open finder click the go button in the menu. Hold down the *Option key go to library then the preferences folder and delete com.apple.airplay.plist. then reboot the system. So far this has seemed to fix the issue for me. if anyone else has tried this I'm curious to hear how it went for them as well.

Comment: I never really did find a good solution, ended up rebuilding my server on a new Mac Mini and the problem went away.  But your solution sounds like it would've been worth trying.  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thank you! It seems it has worked for me. Saving my sanity and enjoyment of my new network-capable receiver. :)

Comment: Since the problem was a bad OS build - I'm closing this as a dupe. If you want it reopened so you can answer with your solution, that would be fine as well. Not having an accepted answer hurts the site and this continues to get "me too" non-answers, so closing it seems the lesser evil.

Comment: valid point... I'll add my eventual solution as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

I have just found some help here: [Disable AirPlay Mirroring](http://www.ehcho.com/guide/disable-airplay-mirroring/). It will let you disable Airplay Mirroring (I assume that includes just the sound) by using a terminal command. It will deny the computer access to the AirPlay.app that allows Airplay mirroring.

`sudo chmod 000 /System/Library/CoreServices/AirPlayUIAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/AirPlayUIAgent`

Some problems are associated with this though. I've copied the article's "drawbacks" below.

> The only drawback to this method is that it locks up the menubar, which means your users won't be able to use any of the menu bar items. They're still able to adjust the volume using the keyboard, though. Logging out and back in will restore the functionality of the menubar until the user tries to use AirPlay mirroring again. I guess if your users complain about the menubar crashing, you know what they've been trying to do! To remove your users temptation of crashing the menu bar all the time, you can hide the AirPlay icon by opening System Preferences > Displays and unchecking the "Show mirroring options in the menu bar when available" checkbox.

if you don't enjoy it afterwards and you want to fix it back to defaults without reinstalling OS X you want to do the same steps above like you did when disabling AirPlay. But instead of the 000 after *sumo chmod* you want to use the numbers 755

You would follow the steps, restart your iMac like before and you should have re-enabled it back

Comment: This is a great solution for a headless music server. If no one logs in except the OP - it will prevent the flakey connection to AirPlay which is an odd bug until the OP can wipe or replace the flakey Mac/OS. (Which is what happened in the end [according to a comment there](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/182470/5472)

Comment: There's an updated script basically executing this idea at https://gist.github.com/thefonso/3294e5d70901226c84b4f8968337380d. It disables other services and stuff too, so likely need to be edited. From the info: "# IMPORTANT: You will need to disable SIP aka Rootless in order to fully execute this script, you can reenable it after.
# WARNING: It might disable things that you may not like. Please double check the services in the TODISABLE vars."
I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/soundflower-landing-page/), the audio routing driver from the Max SP people? It's free.

Set Output to `Soundflower` in `System Preferences`. In your case you will also want to set `Sound Effects` to the same thing.

That will basically capture all the audio on the system and consign it to the bit bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I saw Hotdog Man's answer and from the Settings I muted the Sound Output for the Apple TV device, and switched to a different sound output.

I was then able to turn Airplay off from the Display settings, and no longer received those annoying prompts.

Before I switched the Sound Output setting, I was unable to turn it off from the Display settings.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but all of my Macs have a menu item that says "Turn Off AirPlay Mirroring". It is accessible directly from the AirPlay menu icon, as well as from the Displays preference pane under Settings.

Comment: No such options here... I have "Show mirroring options in the menu bar when available" but there is never any AirPlay menu icon shown.  In fact I've never seen an AirPlay menu icon on any of my Macs (4 of them at the moment).  There is no way that I can find, to disable Airplay.  Also, this issue is strictly about Audio - no video is ever received, just sound (though this may be due to the receiver, I'm not sure).

Comment: It will only show the AirPlay menu icon when a video airplay device is available. Otherwise the sound option is only available under the sound output options in system preferences or by pressing "alt + click" on the volume icon in the menu bar.

Answer (score -2):

Go to *System Preferences* -> *Sound* -> *Output*. There it will say *choose a device for sound output*,with a table listing the Mac's speakers or Apple TV, and if you have headphones then also those.

Comment: Not in my case, as that was the whole problem... Airplay was not being shown.  In the end I replaced it with a different machine and then it stopped trying to connect spontaneously, so it became a non-issue.