# What is AirPlayXPCHelper?

Tags: launchd, malware

I found this in Activity Monitor and there were three of them - the last one keeps rebooting so it can never go
Am I being Hacked?

```
Analysis of sampling AirPlayXPCHelper (pid 21478) every 1 millisecond
Process:         AirPlayXPCHelper [21478]
Path:            /usr/libexec/AirPlayXPCHelper
Load Address:    0x100258000
Identifier:      AirPlayXPCHelper
Version:         615.12.1
Code Type:       ARM64E
Platform:        macOS
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2022-09-28 15:23:12.745 +0100
Launch Time:     2022-09-28 15:22:00.329 +0100
OS Version:      macOS 12.4 (21F79)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /usr/bin/sample

Physical footprint:         5377K
Physical footprint (peak):  5953K
----

Call graph:
    2432 Thread_398676: Main Thread   DispatchQueue_<multiple>
    + 2432 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x18de37080]
    +   2432 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 364  [0x18de383ac]
    +     2432 __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x18de0072c]
    2432 Thread_398681: AMCP Logging Spool
    + 2432 thread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x18de3708c]
    +   2432 _pthread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 148  [0x18de3c26c]
    +     2432 void* caulk::thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<caulk::thread::attributes, void (caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread::*)(), std::__1::tuple<caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread*> > >(void*)  (in caulk) + 96  [0x19688e3cc]
    +       2432 caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread::run()  (in caulk) + 56  [0x19688e7ac]
    +         2432 caulk::mach::semaphore::wait_or_error()  (in caulk) + 28  [0x1968aaa2c]
    +           2432 semaphore_wait_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x18ddfe8ec]
    2432 Thread_398684
    + 2432 thread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x18de3708c]
    +   2432 _pthread_start  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 148  [0x18de3c26c]
    +     2432 void* caulk::thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<caulk::thread::attributes, void (caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread::*)(), std::__1::tuple<caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread*> > >(void*)  (in caulk) + 96  [0x19688e3cc]
    +       2432 caulk::concurrent::details::worker_thread::run()  (in caulk) + 56  [0x19688e7ac]
    +         2432 caulk::mach::semaphore::wait_or_error()  (in caulk) + 28  [0x1968aaa2c]
    +           2432 semaphore_wait_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x18ddfe8ec]
    2432 Thread_398692
    + 2432 _dispatch_sig_thread  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 60  [0x18dc8b5b0]
    +   2432 _dispatch_sigsuspend  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 48  [0x18dc8b5e0]
    +     2432 __sigsuspend_nocancel  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x18de05d70]
    2432 Thread_398724
    + 2432 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x18de37080]
    +   2432 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 364  [0x18de383ac]
    +     2432 __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x18de0072c]
    2432 Thread_398806
    + 2432 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x18de37080]
    +   2432 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 364  [0x18de383ac]
    +     2432 __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x18de0072c]
    2431 Thread_398807
    + 2431 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x18de37080]
    +   2431 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 364  [0x18de383ac]
    +     2431 __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x18de0072c]
    2404 Thread_398721
    + 2404 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x18de37080]
    +   2404 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 364  [0x18de383ac]
    +     2404 __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x18de0072c]
    26 Thread_398721   DispatchQueue_446: com.apple.AirPlay.APTransportKeepAliveControllerStandard.network  (serial)
    + 26 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x18de37080]
    +   26 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 288  [0x18de38360]
    +     26 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 648  [0x18dc8ac98]
    +       26 _dispatch_lane_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 392  [0x18dc80404]
    +         26 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 668  [0x18dc7f8a8]
    +           26 _dispatch_client_callout  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 20  [0x18dc781b4]
    +             26 standardKeepAliveController_sendKeepAliveCallback  (in APTransport) + 572  [0x19cd75d6c]
    +               26 stream_SendMessageCreatingReply  (in APTransport) + 272  [0x19cd87c24]
    +                 26 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 132  [0x18dc78df8]
    +                   26 _dispatch_sema4_wait  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 28  [0x18dc78750]
    +                     26 semaphore_wait_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x18ddfe8ec]
    1 Thread_398721   DispatchQueue_387: APSenderSessionAirPlay.notification.0x5BA0  (serial)
    + 1 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x18de37080]
    +   1 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 288  [0x18de38360]
    +     1 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 648  [0x18dc8ac98]
    +       1 _dispatch_lane_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 392  [0x18dc80404]
    +         1 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 668  [0x18dc7f8a8]
    +           1 _dispatch_client_callout  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 20  [0x18dc781b4]
    +             1 APSDeferredCallback  (in AirPlaySupport) + 32  [0x1b2d6dca0]
    +               1 apsession_postFeedbackReceivedNotificationCallback  (in AirPlaySender) + 56  [0x1bdeab0f8]
    +                 1 CMNotificationCenterPostNotification  (in CoreMedia) + 128  [0x1968bbda0]
    +                   1 CFNotificationCenterPostNotificationWithOptions  (in CoreFoundation) + 136  [0x18defd5a0]
    +                     1 _CFXNotificationPost  (in CoreFoundation) + 632  [0x18decc14c]
    +                       1 CFXNotificationRegistrarFind  (in CoreFoundation) + 284  [0x18e02c6d4]
    +                         1 os_unfair_lock_lock  (in libsystem_platform.dylib) + 0  [0x18de50990]
    1 Thread_398721   DispatchQueue_391: APConnectivityHelperInternalQueue  (serial)
    + 1 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x18de37080]
    +   1 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 288  [0x18de38360]
    +     1 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 648  [0x18dc8ac98]
    +       1 _dispatch_lane_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 392  [0x18dc80404]
    +         1 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 376  [0x18dc7f784]
    +           1 _dispatch_source_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 1596  [0x18dc8e8e0]
    +             1 _dispatch_continuation_pop  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 500  [0x18dc7b670]
    +               1 _dispatch_client_callout  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 20  [0x18dc781b4]
    +                 1 __Apple80211EventMonitoringInit2_block_invoke  (in APTransport) + 80  [0x19cdb223c]
    +                   1 read  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8  [0x18ddff634]
    1 Thread_398807   DispatchQueue_401: APTransportStream.0xBC52  (serial)
      1 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x18de37080]
        1 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 288  [0x18de38360]
          1 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 648  [0x18dc8ac98]
            1 _dispatch_lane_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 392  [0x18dc80404]
              1 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 668  [0x18dc7f8a8]
                1 _dispatch_client_callout  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 20  [0x18dc781b4]
                  1 DYLD-STUB$$free  (in AirPlaySupport) + 0  [0x1b2dadef0]

Total number in stack (recursive counted multiple, when >=5):
        9       start_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 8  [0x18de37080]
        5       __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 0  [0x18de00724]
        5       _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_pthread.dylib) + 364  [0x18de383ac]

Sort by top of stack, same collapsed (when >= 5):
        __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        12131
        semaphore_wait_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        4890
        __sigsuspend_nocancel  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        2432

Binary Images:
       0x100258000 -        0x10025bfff  AirPlayXPCHelper (615.12.1) <DB714476-3F24-3ACA-8A9B-E9C925DE9446> /usr/libexec/AirPlayXPCHelper
       0x1004c8000 -        0x1005250bb  dyld (957) <D9C2A46E-8DC4-3950-9D6A-F799E8CCB683> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x18db61000 -        0x18db62ffe  libsystem_blocks.dylib (79.1) <233D7321-F30D-31D7-8CB4-86B924F902A3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
       0x18db63000 -        0x18dba4ff3  libxpc.dylib (2236.120.5) <84C6E826-0826-36CC-AD70-10288B0050E0> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
       0x18dba5000 -        0x18dbbeffe  libsystem_trace.dylib (1375.100.9) <D72D5CF9-16B3-31E4-B3D6-BFFAED459ADE> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
       0x18dbbf000 -        0x18dc48fef  libcorecrypto.dylib (1218.120.10) <4518B6FC-9A90-337A-A717-9719217F80D8> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
       0x18dc49000 -        0x18dc73ffb  libsystem_malloc.dylib (374.120.1) <5C634686-8D9F-3C7B-9334-B0175DDEF799> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
       0x18dc74000 -        0x18dcbaff7  libdispatch.dylib (1325.120.2) <F9300D47-D3DB-3349-8A6D-ACB68CD9983B> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x18dcbb000 -        0x18dcf8fee  libobjc.A.dylib (841.13) <6FFCCF84-5E0F-34B2-BCBB-BCF98407EA05> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
       0x18dcf9000 -        0x18dcfbfff  libsystem_featureflags.dylib (56) <339C4F6F-9EFB-369A-BC49-FE532FC78100> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_featureflags.dylib
       0x18dcfc000 -        0x18dd7dfff  libsystem_c.dylib (1507.100.9) <86746B94-88E3-342D-B2B2-54303404E492> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
       0x18dd7e000 -        0x18dde4ffb  libc++.1.dylib (1300.25) <D3CFE466-29C6-3E6C-8DB1-FF129B111EE3> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
       0x18dde5000 -        0x18ddfcffb  libc++abi.dylib (1300.25) <59DE363F-98CF-36DC-BECC-4D8F5F4F3A0E> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
       0x18ddfd000 -        0x18de34ffb  libsystem_kernel.dylib (8020.121.3) <03F48DC5-CAA7-3678-AF61-1A3C7FA8B06E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x18de35000 -        0x18de41ff3  libsystem_pthread.dylib (486.100.11) <42166A2C-89A9-3C38-A215-F028544CEA23> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x18de42000 -        0x18de4efff  libdyld.dylib (957) <C64FDD98-C605-3606-9C4D-B12AA011692A> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
       0x18de4f000 -        0x18de56feb  libsystem_platform.dylib (273.100.5) <D7ABA99F-BA00-36E9-945D-48ACF57FC568> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
       0x18de57000 -        0x18de83fff  libsystem_info.dylib (554.120.2) <59F0B56E-E7DD-336E-A17D-C18FF0082757> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
       0x18de84000 -        0x18e3caff1  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1863) <994DB908-11A1-3E43-B7DF-25C09D51368A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
       0x18e3cb000 -        0x18e62bffc  com.apple.LaunchServices (1141.1 - 1141.1) <B89ECA76-99F1-371E-A417-58586DB30812> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
       0x18e62c000 -        0x18e754ffb  com.apple.gpusw.MetalTools (1.0 - 1) <5C2754E7-93FF-3631-B973-C849C5C5FB72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MetalTools.framework/Versions/A/MetalTools
       0x18e755000 -        0x18e9caffb  libBLAS.dylib (1381.100.10) <5C8035B2-139D-3BF6-A585-D4D3B731CBAF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
       0x18e9cb000 -        0x18ea12ff3  com.apple.Lexicon-framework (1.0 - 98.1) <CB06EC44-ADF1-3941-811A-9CE7946BF7B3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Lexicon.framework/Versions/A/Lexicon
       0x18ea13000 -        0x18ea79ff7  libSparse.dylib (108.120.2) <B69A4251-03B1-3CC2-85DA-CC0034709E96> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparse.dylib
       0x18ea7a000 -        0x18eaffff3  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.21 - 1.21) <DF669A12-06ED-3BBF-904C-5A29FDA26559> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
       0x18eb00000 -        0x18eb33ff7  libCRFSuite.dylib (51) <906D18BF-6D0F-3E2F-B5A4-EE4AD28B28E9> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
       0x18eb34000 -        0x18ed86ff4  libmecabra.dylib (972.11) <1216C039-2954-3B69-8F1E-EFEFC4261589> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
       0x18ed87000 -        0x18f178ffc  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1863) <A2E534D9-CDF0-397F-A41E-147559C83893> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
       0x18f179000 -        0x18f278ffb  com.apple.LanguageModeling (1.0 - 277.4) <2DE2AF9F-B645-3554-978E-282C9B04B709> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/Versions/A/LanguageModeling
       0x18f279000 -        0x18f398ff2  com.apple.CoreDisplay (265.3 - 265.3) <A8A976DD-BC59-3E67-9646-C696D865421F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreDisplay.framework/Versions/A/CoreDisplay
       0x18f399000 -        0x18f63cfeb  com.apple.audio.AudioToolboxCore (1.0 - 1245.85) <6EFEEF2C-B075-3D75-B640-63FFA48C7197> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AudioToolboxCore.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolboxCore
       0x18f63d000 -        0x18f818ff6  com.apple.CoreText (710.5.0.1 - 710.5.0.1) <F3954C25-69D1-3F8C-AA80-4F2ECB2FDEE7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
       0x18f819000 -        0x18ff3cff6  com.apple.audio.CoreAudio (5.0 - 5.0) <4A0BB421-67C9-3849-A01E-A67D27FC1604> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
       0x18ff3d000 -        0x1902bbfff  com.apple.security (7.0 - 60158.120.9) <DBE12E9A-C21A-3D4A-B1A0-79A05D7387EB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
       0x1902bc000 -        0x190571ff7  libicucore.A.dylib (70104.2) <B828A81C-77BB-3B55-9C92-7F5407755F50> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
       0x190572000 -        0x19057cff3  libsystem_darwin.dylib (1507.100.9) <53E5EEEC-AAE7-34B0-9D0C-E64CF9933D6F> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
       0x19057d000 -        0x190878ff5  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1319 - 1319) <1C5B8CFF-4EE3-35BE-9C68-85F45046E1DC> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
       0x1908b6000 -        0x1908f3ffd  com.apple.CSStore (1141.1 - 1141.1) <740FA24E-BB0A-3843-98AA-014FFC541ED2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesStore.framework/Versions/A/CoreServicesStore
       0x1908f4000 -        0x1909caff2  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1955.121.2) <6A11949E-7C1E-3792-8A15-8C45D5C7E228> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
       0x1909cb000 -        0x1909dafff  libsystem_notify.dylib (301) <9A888C07-226F-3976-9306-DF9649297478> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
       0x1909db000 -        0x190a2bfff  libsandbox.1.dylib (1657.120.6) <23802CA1-0DB2-3532-BB55-53E8A41575A2> /usr/lib/libsandbox.1.dylib
       0x190a2c000 -        0x1918e3ff9  com.apple.AppKit (6.9 - 2113.50.132) <A773DD23-B1C8-3C9B-9175-9A71D210ACE0> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
       0x1918e4000 -        0x191b54ffc  com.apple.UIFoundation (1.0 - 787.3) <27460340-DC0F-33AB-9229-BFE7B5368988> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/Versions/A/UIFoundation
       0x191b55000 -        0x191b68ff3  com.apple.UniformTypeIdentifiers (709 - 709) <17D540B6-8D39-3947-BB21-1C48279F235F> /System/Library/Frameworks/UniformTypeIdentifiers.framework/Versions/A/UniformTypeIdentifiers
       0x191ffe000 -        0x192a90ff7  libnetwork.dylib (2750.120.19.0.1) <9B675697-296D-3C42-9A56-D459BB38F5CC> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
       0x192a91000 -        0x192f45ffa  com.apple.CFNetwork (1333.0.4 - 1333.0.4) <A3011783-18D8-33EF-A04F-EBB14FCC2AB5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
       0x192f46000 -        0x192f5eff7  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (1471.120.10.0.2) <017E7EB2-7742-3BDE-9271-37D0C7ED093B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
       0x192f5f000 -        0x192f60fff  libenergytrace.dylib (23) <3C1E2833-A2A1-3312-9CF4-91D2A2249CA5> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
       0x192f61000 -        0x192fb7fda  libMobileGestalt.dylib (1073.100.31.0.1) <D9F3207D-D483-3993-9CB7-7FC5899D924B> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
       0x192fb8000 -        0x192fcfff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (392.100.2) <52E0B826-9FD0-38B6-A6E2-7053A2D03410> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
       0x192fd0000 -        0x192febff9  com.apple.TCC (1.0 - 1) <24087C32-6CB5-39AC-8C4F-BDABAFCA5F74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
       0x192fec000 -        0x1933c4ff7  com.apple.SkyLight (1.600.0 - 671.11) <89279AD8-37E3-3EC1-B51F-A8065053FF05> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/SkyLight
       0x1933c5000 -        0x1939d2ff3  com.apple.CoreGraphics (2.0 - 1557.6.4) <ADE21D28-C540-3AE4-BF28-2C6DE6F2F79F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
       0x1939d3000 -        0x193ad1ff7  com.apple.ColorSync (4.13.0 - 3521.6.2) <590C32F8-4089-368A-8A47-F4A7B84BF18E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
       0x193ad2000 -        0x193b31ff0  com.apple.HIServices (1.22 - 739.1) <5F172978-BF24-38EE-B2F6-7BB9F00AA2A8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
       0x193b32000 -        0x193b71fff  libAWDSupport.dylib (954.1) <53E1E3BF-FC52-3140-977C-C92E3DD384B6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libAWDSupport.dylib
       0x193b72000 -        0x193bd6fff  libprotobuf.dylib (5501) <3AD7673B-9079-31DC-AE91-DCDEEE37630F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libprotobuf.dylib
       0x193bd7000 -        0x193beafff  libprotobuf-lite.dylib (5501) <207E1AF1-9F1B-3DEA-BC82-6AC99D88C213> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libprotobuf-lite.dylib
       0x193beb000 -        0x193c32ff1  com.apple.awd (1.0 - 954.1) <2913E494-AACE-34BD-8665-42A117F3D797> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/Versions/A/WirelessDiagnostics
       0x193f3f000 -        0x194314ff4  com.apple.CoreData (120 - 1152.1) <484433A8-5452-31A4-96E9-BBD069D6DB3B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
       0x194315000 -        0x19432efff  com.apple.ProtocolBuffer (1 - 288.22.9.15.1) <7A3BB668-6681-3C03-A212-96E376FB537B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/Versions/A/ProtocolBuffer
       0x19432f000 -        0x1944eeffb  libsqlite3.dylib (331.5) <5F6D1ADD-8D1C-3B92-9D65-C4F60A3FF3F6> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
       0x194587000 -        0x194642ffa  com.apple.BaseBoard (567.5 - 567.5) <4585672B-0C82-3F14-8EA5-9B14DDF39F10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/Versions/A/BaseBoard
       0x194643000 -        0x19469dffe  com.apple.RunningBoardServices (1.0 - 618.100.42) <79C0EA2C-575C-3D45-BECF-7C0202C2020A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RunningBoardServices.framework/Versions/A/RunningBoardServices
       0x19469e000 -        0x19470effb  com.apple.AE (924 - 924) <F2787793-99F4-3D68-B98D-0F71C7B9AC52> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
       0x19470f000 -        0x194717ffc  libdns_services.dylib (1557.120.7) <49D070A5-A310-37AE-9A20-113CF41E9022> /usr/lib/libdns_services.dylib
       0x194718000 -        0x194720fff  libsystem_symptoms.dylib (1617.120.7) <0EC2FFF6-8CB7-3E4D-8568-4976E52CFC53> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
       0x194721000 -        0x1948c9ffa  com.apple.Network (1.0 - 1) <29B29424-71F9-32AE-B1CD-A4C908ED30EE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Network.framework/Versions/A/Network
       0x1948ca000 -        0x1948fafff  com.apple.analyticsd (1.0 - 1) <B32967AE-87EF-308E-954F-77ADF5D33A21> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAnalytics.framework/Versions/A/CoreAnalytics
       0x1948fb000 -        0x1948fdfff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (112) <E41695A1-532C-39DD-ACEE-4260D105F2CC> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
       0x1948fe000 -        0x19494effc  com.apple.spotlight.metadata.utilities (1.0 - 2183.20) <A0D3E836-431C-37E2-841C-4C374137740F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MetadataUtilities.framework/Versions/A/MetadataUtilities
       0x19494f000 -        0x1949eeff7  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 2183.20) <6724A99C-386B-39A5-8C21-0B274FBE06E4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
       0x1949ef000 -        0x1949f6fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.7 - 2.7) <95956A3A-01B1-39EB-811E-D193B405766D> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
       0x1949f7000 -        0x194d7aff3  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - 555.3) <7B72A195-4E16-3829-9AC7-4EB4A828BB44> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
       0x194d7b000 -        0x1950a8ffc  com.apple.QuartzCore (1.11 - 964.28) <7A5838A0-104B-3896-9C99-66EE81786497> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
       0x1950a9000 -        0x1950f8ffa  libFontRegistry.dylib (333.2.0.1) <D17A5056-1190-325C-8287-42FF5E114033> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
       0x1950f9000 -        0x195236ffc  com.apple.coreui (2.1 - 738.1) <46DE086F-876C-3814-87AA-25FB12CE2B97> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
       0x195333000 -        0x19533eff9  com.apple.PerformanceAnalysis (1.302.4 - 302.4) <0DE12BCE-D891-3072-B6E3-051B82ECFA87> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PerformanceAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/PerformanceAnalysis
       0x19533f000 -        0x19534eff9  com.apple.OpenDirectory (12.4 - 233) <18406DD3-15F9-3C65-9E1A-8A2E0001EBD9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/OpenDirectory
       0x19534f000 -        0x19536efff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory (12.4 - 233) <55619F3F-CDDA-3FEF-8E49-8E38889D426F> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
       0x19536f000 -        0x19537bfff  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1326.100.8 - 1326.100.8) <39779C50-E769-3214-BB5E-683AAA7F9CE0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
       0x19537c000 -        0x1953a2fff  com.apple.coreservices.SharedFileList (155 - 155) <14470AE9-0327-37AE-946A-E7A3203E47A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SharedFileList.framework/Versions/A/SharedFileList
       0x1953a3000 -        0x1953a5fff  libapp_launch_measurement.dylib (16) <4BF3B886-D19A-3727-9050-015861576AC0> /usr/lib/libapp_launch_measurement.dylib
       0x1953a6000 -        0x1953f0ff9  com.apple.CoreAutoLayout (1.0 - 28) <891A7053-1B59-3520-A1B7-7D0430A56B0F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAutoLayout.framework/Versions/A/CoreAutoLayout
       0x1953f1000 -        0x1954deff7  libxml2.2.dylib (35.9) <1C94F5B5-A536-3CF7-8C97-8DCF4D219076> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
       0x1954df000 -        0x19553cff4  com.apple.CoreVideo (1.8 - 475.2) <66746BAE-3892-303B-8144-E8568A7904E7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
       0x19670d000 -        0x19672bfff  libsystem_containermanager.dylib (383.120.2) <F359A79F-925A-3CF7-A922-7AA2A1DA126B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
       0x19672c000 -        0x19673fff5  com.apple.IOSurface (302.14 - 302.14) <A24E88F3-EAA9-3421-983F-487783D9EEE2> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
       0x196740000 -        0x196749ff9  com.apple.IOAccelerator (462.8 - 462.8) <72C0842E-A38A-38EA-96BA-B81CE311A594> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/Versions/A/IOAccelerator
       0x19674a000 -        0x19688bffd  com.apple.Metal (263.8 - 263.8) <FE2C16E1-6E67-3FC0-A9A0-3479BF97EF68> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Versions/A/Metal
       0x19688c000 -        0x1968b2ff7  com.apple.audio.caulk (1.0 - 92) <AF5B85D3-350B-3B8F-9D21-5D4B431DBCD9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/caulk.framework/Versions/A/caulk
       0x1968b3000 -        0x1969c8fff  com.apple.CoreMedia (1.0 - 2945.12.1) <94410AB1-CDBA-38C0-85BD-15377EF20C8C> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Versions/A/CoreMedia
       0x1969c9000 -        0x196b0cff4  libFontParser.dylib (329.5.0.1) <AEDF6AFE-17AA-37F1-89B8-DA37E7E3C4CD> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
       0x196b0d000 -        0x196e40ff8  com.apple.HIToolbox (2.1.1 - 1114.1) <F842B96A-54F3-36F3-9B94-B258FAE1B7EB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
       0x196e41000 -        0x196e58fff  com.apple.framework.DFRFoundation (1.0 - 271) <150E95AC-A93B-3C9C-BFC9-B83268756BE6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DFRFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DFRFoundation
       0x196e59000 -        0x196e5dffb  com.apple.dt.XCTTargetBootstrap (20500) <6D3FE059-43A1-3A51-8B58-D4B94E0C23A2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCTTargetBootstrap.framework/Versions/A/XCTTargetBootstrap
       0x196e5e000 -        0x196e8dffb  com.apple.CoreSVG (1.0 - 175.5.1) <5752FDD4-6D67-31BE-B46C-F776D64A466C> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSVG.framework/Versions/A/CoreSVG
       0x196e8e000 -        0x1970dcff7  com.apple.ImageIO (3.3.0 - 2222.6.4) <86163688-7E40-3190-A6A3-78D31AF1B530> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
```

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217253/little-snitch-reports-outgoing-connections-for-airplayxpchelper-for-wrong-subnet or Google your question title.

Comment: Please have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/editing to understand why people here can and will edit posts by others.

Comment: Also, in general, it is rather difficult to answer a "Am I being hacked" question without having access to the system. A running AirPlayXPCHelper process for sure is not a sign for this, neither is having three of them. Do you have additional indications regarding a potential attack?

Answer (score 7):

No, you aren't. AirPlayXPCHelper is a process of Airplay, a built-in feature of macOS.

Comment: This isn't the answer to my question

Comment: This is absolutely the answer to the question!

Comment: AirPlay is a *feature* of MacOS, but it's totally unnecessary bloat and burns CPU and can be disabled, *unless* you actually have Apple TV or display or sound devices. Blanket-calling it "built-in" implies way too much usefulness. Just because Apple makes it hard to disable the ever-increasing layers of bloat in successive versions of MacOS [Disable AirPlay on a Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53628/disable-airplay-on-a-mac), doesn't mean these processes are doing anything useful.